# Filter / Report Builder 2008 R2

Tags: filter, teradata, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I have an unusual situation for a report. I only want to display rows for  several accounts (170, 171, 200, 380) if the Cost Center is either A480 or A485. All other accounts should be displayed for all cost centers. If one of the above accounts appears on any other cost center, then it should NOT be displayed in the report.

I thought I may need an expression like “='A480' or 'A485' for the Value field (using IN) but I’m not sure what the Expression field should look like.  I'm doing this all within Report Builder.

My report returns data for a number of accounts for a number of cost centers.  For example: Account Numbers: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145 / 170 / 171 / 200 / 380

What I would like the report to do is only display accounts 170 / 171 / 200 / 380 for Cost Centers A480 and A485.

Sample Results:

```
Cost Center A400: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145 
Cost Center A440: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145 
Cost Center A480: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145 / 170 / 171 / 200 / 380
Cost Center A485: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145 / 170 / 171 / 200 / 380
Cost Center A500: 123 / 125 / 130 / 140 / 145
```

Accounts 170 / 171 / 200 / 380 should only be displayed if the Cost Center is A480 or A485. The report has a prompt for Cost Center. Some of the other Cost Centers will have results for accounts 170 / 171 / 200 / 380 but the user doesn't want to see these accounts in the any Cost Center other than A480 or A485.

Thanks for your help........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex scenarios than a simple filter like the one you describe, you need to implement an expression that covers all cases involving some nested IIFS.

For example:

```
=IIF(
    Fields!CostCenter.Value = "A480" or Fields!CostCenter.Value = "A485", 
    1, 
    IIF(
        Fields!Account.Value = "170" or Fields!Account.Value = "171" or Fields!Account.Value = "200" or Fields!Account.Value = "300", 
        0, 
        1))
```

The first IIF covers the special cases of A480 and A485, allowing true for each row with *any* account number.  The second IIF (for all other cost centers) returns a 0 for the excluded account numbers.  Now you just have to setup a simple filter on the report (either on the table or the dataset) that only keeps rows that this expression returns 1 for.

Comment: @Daniel...........Thanks.........I'm going to give this a try today.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @Daniel...........I had to modify the filter to use the parameter values in the expression [(=IIF(Parameters!GP.Value = "A0480" or Parameters!GP.Value = "A0485", 1, IIF(Fields!FA_ACCT.Value = 170203 or Fields!FA_ACCT.Value = 171040 or Fields!FA_ACCT.Value = 171041 or Fields!FA_ACCT.Value = 200380, 0, 1))}.  I used "=' as the operator and then I used =cdec(1)  as the value.  It removes the 4 accounts from all cost centers including A0480 and A0485.  The FA_ACCT field is defined as Char(10).  Can you tell me what is wrong with this?  Thanks for your help.....

Comment: Hmm, by using parameter values instead of field values you have actually changed the logic in the expressions.  Consider the case where your multivalue parameter = "A0480,A0482,A0483,A0485"  (think of multivalue parameters as comma deliminated strings).  When the expression is parsed, your parameter is not equal to A0480 nor A0485, so the first IIF will always failover.  Is it possible to add the GP parameter as a field within your query so that you can reference it in your expression as a field? This would allow row level evaluation of your expression.

Comment: @Daniel................That did the trick.  I was able to add the group value to the field and then changed the filter to use the group field.  It does exactly what I was looking to do.  Thanks for your help....